# Setting a private IP on AWS ElastiCache Redis

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have a 2 AWS ElastiCache Groups both launched into separate VPCs.

I have 2 VPCs, one being named `staging`, and the other named `production`.

I am able to connect to the ElastiCache redis instances from within my instances just fine.

What I would like to do, is force the redis instances to be ip address `10.0.1.60` in both VPCs.

Is this possible?  What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think it is possible because that's the point with ElasticCache on AWS - they can change the IP without notice. So they highly recommend using the DNS names because they can replace cache nodes automatically when needed.

Comment: Forgot to mention that you can use an environment value on your machines, like REDIS_ENDPOINT -on staging it will have the endpoint of staging redis while on the production machines it will have the redis endpoint of the production redis.

Comment: @lcostea thanks, I think I might be able to accomplish something similar with the private dns with route 53, setting up something like redis.internal.example.com to point to the elastic cache in both vpcs, keeping the addresses the same.  If that doesn't work I guess i'll fall back to environment variables like you mention